# Yocto: bitbake exit code confusion

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto

I get an error while building an image using Yocto (dizzy):

```
ERROR: Creation of tar /mnt/workspace/build/tmp/deploy/tar/xev-dbg-1.2.1-r0.tar.gz failed.
```

and `bitbake` command fails with the following report:

```
No currently running tasks (6291 of 6292)
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 6292 tasks of which 18 didn't need to be rerun and all succeeded.
Summary: There were 13 WARNING messages shown.
Summary: There were 3 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

If I check the file `xev-dbg-1.2.1-r0.tar.gz`, I get:

```
$ file  /mnt/workspace/build/tmp/deploy/tar/xev-dbg-1.2.1-r0.tar.gz
/mnt/workspace/build/tmp/deploy/tar/xev-dbg-1.2.1-r0.tar.gz: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Mon Mar 27 20:19:55 201
```

and it is the same case for the remaining two errors.

I am confused:

- if there was an error, why `bitbake` is reporting that all tasks  succeeded?
- If the file were successfully created, why `bitbake` exits with non zero value?

Answer (score 2):

Bitbake did not return a 0 exit-code.  This mean that there are errors in the bitbake process.

There are 3 errors when it is trying to create the tar files as shown.
The compressed file is there but it is not complete. E.g. Just like how you could download a file and interrupt it and the download file is still there.  So we usually use md5sum or some kind of hash number to check on the completeness of the file.

A better understanding might be: Bitbake attempted to run 6292 task.  18 of them do not need to rerun.  Bitbake attempted to rerun the rest 6274(6292-18) and succeeded in rerunning them. This does not mean that all of them are successfully compiled.  In the process of rerunning them, there are 13 warnings and and 3 errors appeared.  Because of the 3 errors, bitbake returns with a non-zero exit code.

```
No currently running tasks (6291 of 6292)
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 6292 tasks of which 18 didn't need to be rerun and all succeeded.
Summary: There were 13 WARNING messages shown.
Summary: There were 3 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```